# How do I manipulate LaTeX transliteration system in a table

Tags: tables, arabic

I am writing with Arabic character in a table and I want to manipulate the transliteration system to get a proper display.

The code is below;

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Description of AWN.}
\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{ l | p{3cm} | l | l | l }
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
 & \textbf{Antonym seed}\hspace*{6mm} & \textbf{Translation}\hspace*{4mm} & \textbf{Frequency}\hspace*{4mm} & \textbf{LogDice}\hspace*{4mm} \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{1} & \<قريب, بعيد> & far near & 47,044 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{2} & \<قليل, كثير> & d & 21,107 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{3} & \<حيَ, ميت> & d & 4,505 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{4} & \<أكبر, أصغر> & d & 5,358 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{5} & \<غني, فقير> & d & 2,564 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{6} & \<جديد, قديم> & d & 3,453 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{7} & \<حر, عبد> & d & 4,390 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{8} & \<قصير, طويل> & dd & 2,106 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{9} & \<شرقي, غربي> & k & 2,757 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{10} & \<صالح, طالح> & d & 1,566 &  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want the transliteration to be **under** the Arabic words not **next** to it.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you please edit your MWE to be a full, compilable example, beginning with `\documentlcass` and ending in `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only a snippet rather than a complete example, it’s difficult to understand and address your concerns.  I tried to add the missing elements, and the first problem that appeared was the gaps in the vertical lines separating columns.  But vertical lines in tables are almost always undesirable, so I removed them along with the bold type, substituting `booktabs` and small caps.  With those aesthetic problems out of the way, what I take to be your difficulty became noticeable: you want the transliteration below the Arabic, and you’re trying to force that to happen by restricting the column width to 3cm, but the result is transliteration sometimes below and sometimes on the same line as the Arabic.

You appear to be using `arabtex` with the `pdftex` engine.  The `arabtex` package is extremely complex, and unless an expert performs major surgery on it, I doubt you’ll get it to put transliterations where you want them.  You can force the issue by making the column width smaller, but there will be warnings about overfull and underfull boxes, and the output looks sloppy, in part because the Arabic should be aligned on the right:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,lmodern,arabtex,utf8}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{1ex}
\begin{document}
\setcode{utf8}
\transtrue
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \linespread{1.1035}
  \caption{Description of AWN.}
  \label{tab2}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}rp{2cm}crl@{}}
    \toprule
    & \scshape Antonym seed & \scshape Translation & \scshape Frequency & \scshape LogDice\\
    \midrule
    1. & \<قريب, بعيد> & far near & 47,044 & \\
    2. & \<قليل, كثير> & d & 21,107 & \\
    3. & \<حيَ, ميت> & d & 4,505 & \\
    4. & \<أكبر, أصغر> & d & 5,358 & \\
    5. & \<غني, فقير> & d & 2,564 & \\
    6. & \<جديد, قديم> & d & 3,453 & \\
    7. & \<حر, عبد> & d & 4,390 & \\
    8. & \<قصير, طويل> & dd & 2,106 & \\
    9. & \<شرقي, غربي> & k & 2,757 & \\
    10. & \<صالح, طالح> & d & 1,566 & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above example]

Contrast the appearance if we let `arabtex` put the transliteration where it was designed to place it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,lmodern,arabtex,utf8}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{1ex}
\begin{document}
\setcode{utf8}
\transtrue
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \linespread{1.1035}
  \caption{Description of AWN.}
  \label{tab2}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}rrcrl@{}}
    \toprule
    & \scshape Antonym seed & \scshape Translation & \scshape Frequency & \scshape LogDice\\
    \midrule
    1. & \<قريب, بعيد> & far near & 47,044 & \\
    2. & \<قليل, كثير> & d & 21,107 & \\
    3. & \<حيَ, ميت> & d & 4,505 & \\
    4. & \<أكبر, أصغر> & d & 5,358 & \\
    5. & \<غني, فقير> & d & 2,564 & \\
    6. & \<جديد, قديم> & d & 3,453 & \\
    7. & \<حر, عبد> & d & 4,390 & \\
    8. & \<قصير, طويل> & dd & 2,106 & \\
    9. & \<شرقي, غربي> & k & 2,757 & \\
    10. & \<صالح, طالح> & d & 1,566 & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second example]

That’s better, though still not ideal.  To improve it, I’d turn off automatic transliteration, add a left-aligned column with the header “Transliteration,” and enter the transliteration manually.  That’s tedious, but not impossible.

You may find `arabxetex` more flexible.